# How can I project a power line net in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am working with power lines net using the software QGIS. I would like to know which plugins or tools do I need to be able drawing (projecting) them.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using the Network Analysis library.  This will allow you to create graphs, digraphs, networks, etc.  Here is a link to [a tutorial](http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html), and here is one on the more powerful [Python API](https://qgis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/12_network_analysis.html).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to "show" power lines in QGIS is to have a source from which you can draw lines. I guess you are working in power system company. I'm sure you have some kind of GIS or GIS data? Power lines in QGIS are just polylines taken from source like your spatial databases or CAD drawings. You don't need any plugins to do that. Another thing is study of topology based calculations that are necessary for power system study. For that you need to build topology rules that are complex in power system due to switches in substations, switching substations etc.

For basic asset/spatial analysis QGIS is just fine.